# Using cut to parse string and check if the contents exist

Tags: bash, variables, cut

I'm writing a script and I have a variable `MINIENTREGA_FICHEROS="informe.txt programa.c"`

This variable can contain any number of files separated with a blank space. What I need to do is to check the current folder to make sure those files exist and tell the user. What I thought might be appropriate for this situation was to use `cut` to separate all words from each other and assign each one to a local variable. Afterwards use `if [ -e $var ]` inside of a for and echo the result, or something along those lines.

Any advice?

Comment: Use an array to hold the file names, not a single string parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cut` is best used when the required field(s) are previously known, i.e.to select a column/columns from text. I think, a simple `do` loop is much better suited here:

```
 MINIENTREGA_FICHEROS="informe.txt programa.c"
 for i in $MINIENTREGA_FICHEROS; do 
   [ ! -e $i ] &&  echo 'file "'$i'" is missing'
 done
```

Output:

```
 file "informe.txt" is missing
 file "programa.c" is missing
```

EDIT: To be precise, the first command is only included here to actually initialize the variable in your shell if you try out the command. If it is already present (e.g. when using it inside a script), you should omit it.

Comment: The `export` is not necessary or useful here. Its purpose is to make a variable visible to subprocesses, but you are not starting any processes which use this variable for anything.

Comment: Yes, I know... I wanted to post something you could copy&paste into your terminal, yet be readable.

Comment: And omitting `export` would hinder that how?

Comment: Yes, I guess you would not have that variable present in your environment ;-) I added it to the answer.

Comment: You can take out the seven characters "`export `" and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

That will work, although it requires that none of your files have spaces in their names. (As @chepner points out in a comment, you could avoid this problem by making `$MINIENTREGA_FICHEROS` an array rather than a simple string; of course, that will change the way you construct that variable.)

In any event, there is a much simpler approach which will also work:

```
ls $MINIENTREGA_FICHEROS > /dev/null || exit 1

# If you change the variable to an array, this becomes:
ls "${MINIENTREGA_FICHEROS[@]}" > /dev/null || exit 1
```

Note: I *deliberately* left out the quotes around the variable expansion in the first line.

This takes advantage of the fact that `ls` will generate an error message on `stderr` for each filename supplied as an argument if the file doesn't exist. Redirectly `stdout` to `/dev/null` eliminates the echo of the filenames, which would just be distracting. `|| exit` causes the script to exit if any of the files doesn't exist. That may or may not be what you want; if it is not what you want, leave it out.

Comment: Since the question is tagged `bash`, you may as well use an array to hold the file names, then use `ls "${MINIENTREGA_FICHEROS[@]}" > /dev/null`. Then this will work for any valid file name.

Comment: @chepner: +1. I thought about that originally but it seemed to just confuse a simple point I was trying to make ("bash is best used as glue"). However, it is also a useful point, so I added it.

Comment: Fair enough. One of the OP's other questions suggests that working an array into his overall script might prove tricky (he's currently `export`ing `MINIENTREGA`).

Comment: Right. `bash` lets you export functions (at the cost of making some string values not exportable) but afaik doesn't yet allow arrays to be exported. That should be mentioned more prominently somewhere but I don't think this answer is the place.